# Querying for File properties plus ListItemAllFields properties

Tags: client-object-model

I'm trying to retrieve both a file's Id in its list, plus its ETag, using the following snippet;

```
using (var clientContext = new ClientContext(webUrl))
{
    var results = clientContext.Web.Lists
        .GetById(listId).RootFolder.Files;

    clientContext.Load(results, files => files
            .Include(file => file.ETag)
            .Include(file => file.ListItemAllFields.Id));

    clientContext.ExecuteQuery();
    foreach (var file in results)
    {
        Console.WriteLine(file.ETag + " " + file.ListItemAllFields.Id);
    }
}
```

However, I'm getting the following exception;

> The query expression 'files => files.Include(new [] {file =>
>   file.ETag}).Include(new [] {file =>
>   Convert(file.ListItemAllFields.Id)})' is not supported.

Am I forming my query correctly? It seems that if I query for the ETag by itself, then the query works. And also, if I query for the ListItemAllFields.Id by itself, then the query works.

It's when they are both included in the one query that the failure occurs.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Managed to work this one out with a bit of trial and error. The correct form of the query is;

```
clientContext.Load(results,
    files => files.Include(file => file.ETag),
    files => files.Include(file => file.ListItemAllFields.Id));
```

Hopefully that's of some use to anyone else who encounters this issue.

Comment: Yes this is right. Also this same thing can help you get a Folder itemId.

Comment: I knew it would be useful to someone! Didn't know it would be 7 years later, but worth it :)

Comment: yeah when you contribute to stack exchange, you will be someone's hero 1,000's of miles away many years later.